# unexpected '(', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

this code keep telling me;

> unexpected '(', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\wamp\www\project\side_tab.php on line 24

```
 function ongoing_cases_control(isAdmin()){
          if(isAdmin() == 1) {
          echo '
            <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="panel panel-primary">
                           <div class="panel-heading">Ongoing Cases Panel</div>
                              <div class="panel-body">  
                                <p>You can edit, add on ongoing cases</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

          ';
 }
```

Comment: What is `isAdmin()`? The function definition is expecting a variable there, not another function. Check the PHP documentation for function arguments for more info. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: was just going to say that ^

Comment: isAdmin() should be a variable and not a function

Comment: Please do not forget your question next  time. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a variable, then you can pass the result of a function

```
function ongoing_cases_control($isAdmin)
{
    if ($isAdmin) { // Note "== 1" will be true for any value that evaluates to true, so might as well just check for any value that evaluates to true.
        // Return the result so you don't have side effects
        return '
        <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="panel panel-primary">
                       <div class="panel-heading">Ongoing Cases Panel</div>
                          <div class="panel-body">  
                            <p>You can edit, add on ongoing cases</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

      ';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
echo ongoing_cases_control(isAdmin());
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is expecting a variable, you have given an expression, thats why it is an error

```
function ongoing_cases_control(isAdmin())
```

Here `isAdmin()` is a function, you have to put a variable there.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 problems assuming this is the whole snippet. you cannot put an expression in a function declaration, and you have missed a closing `}`.

```
 function ongoing_cases_control($isAdmin) { // <--- replace with a variable
          if($isAdmin == 1) {
          echo '
            <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="panel panel-primary">
                           <div class="panel-heading">Ongoing Cases Panel</div>
                              <div class="panel-body">  
                                <p>You can edit, add on ongoing cases</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

          ';
          } // <---- here
 }
```